# Как создать колонку по 2 условиям?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо создать столбец со значениями наиболее часто встречающихся для этого адреса дат.

```
d = {'name': [['rick', 'mike', 'morty'], 'NaN', ['brick', 'nick'], ['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer'], ['rick', 'morty']],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '11/05/2011'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'AR', 'AR'],
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Нужно постараться не использовать циклы.
Должно получиться так

```
d = {'name': [['rick', 'mike', 'morty'], 'NaN', ['brick', 'nick'], ['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer'], ['rick', 'morty']],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '11/05/2011'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'AR', 'AR'],
     'Temp': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '11/05/2011', '11/05/2011']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Comment: Ваше задание будет принято, при одном условии, если вы удосужитесь разместить какие трудности у вас возникли при её решении.

Comment: Я могу это сделать при помощи двойного поиска моды, но это долго и много кода. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли иные способы решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно попробовать что-то вроде этого:

```
df['Temp'] = df.groupby('Address')['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])

>>> df
'''
                          name        Date Address        Temp
0          [rick, mike, morty]  11/05/2011      AR  11/05/2011
1                          NaN   9/02/2010      YU   9/02/2010
2                [brick, nick]   1/01/2014      RU   1/01/2014
3  [rick, reaven, bart, homer]  12/20/2020      AR  11/05/2011
4                [rick, morty]  11/05/2011      AR  11/05/2011
```

Comment: До сих пор не очень понимаю в чём разница `apply` и `transform` )

Comment: А если усложнить задачу- не создавать новую колонку, а заменить отсутствующие значения в колонке даты: d = {'name': [['rick', 'mike', 'morty'], 'NaN', ['brick', 'nick'], ['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer'], ['rick', 'morty']],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', NaN, '11/05/2011'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'AR', 'AR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off попробуйте так `df['Date'] = df.groupby('Address')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))` но возможно будет лучше оформить это отдельным вопросом

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Придётся повторить этот раздел(